# Honeycomb context menu with full screen confusion

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb

I'm trying to understand what the new approach to the menu is in Honeycomb (and beyond).

If I set my version to < 11 the menu hotkey appears at the bottom and everything works as it did in pre honeycomb days.

terrific.

however, if I set my versino to 11+ then the hotkey no longer appears and now the menu button is in the top right corner... it's missing the icons, but at least the menu options still work as before.

great...

HOWEVER

if I'm running my app full screen AND it's an v11+ then my menu is simply gone.

I notice that the Kindle app offers something akin to a toggle. When you tap anywhere on the screen that isn't a button of some kind, the app flips from fullscreen mode to regular mode and the menu appears at the top.

Is this something that the App developers did manually, or is there a feature of Honeycomb that I haven't noticed that facilitates this full/non-full screen toggle for apps that have menues semi-automatically?

Answer (score 2):

I dont think Honeycomb has the feature you described. It is something specific to Kindle app.